# Can't setText on header textview

Tags: android, header, settext

I'm having trouble getting my setText on a header Item to work without error. I've tried calling

```
 TextView head = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storyTitle);
         head.setText(st.getString(st.getColumnIndex("titledesc")));
```

In my runnable, in my filldata() and in my on create. If I have the 2nd line of that code it crashes. If not it runs but wont get the result I need. I feel like I'm missing something but don't understand why this doesn't work for the header when it does for everything else.

```
public class output extends ListActivity {
    private PopupWindow pw;
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;
    private int getCount = inputpage.editCount;
    private Map<Integer, String> values = inputpage.inputValues; 
    private Cursor st;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstantState);
        setContentView(R.layout.outview);
        mydbhelper = new dbadapter(this);
        mydbhelper.open();
        fillData();
        }
      //Lots of long if statements to insure all text changed has the new color, for statement only colors last item in loop    
private final Runnable mTask = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         TextView head = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storyTitle);
         head.setText(st.getString(st.getColumnIndex("titledesc")));

        if ( getCount == 1){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
    textView.setText(modifitedText);
                }
        if ( getCount == 2){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText1);
                }
        if ( getCount == 3){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText2);
                }
        if ( getCount == 4){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText3 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText2, 
                    "3", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(3) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText3);
                }
        if ( getCount == 5){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText3 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText2, 
                    "3", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(3) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText4 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText3, 
                    "4", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(4) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText4);
                }
        if ( getCount == 6){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText3 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText2, 
                    "3", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(3) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText4 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText3, 
                    "4", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(4) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText5 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText4, 
                    "5", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(5) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText5);
                }
        if ( getCount == 7){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText3 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText2, 
                    "3", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(3) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText4 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText3, 
                    "4", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(4) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText5 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText4, 
                    "5", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(5) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText6 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText5, 
                    "6", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(6) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText6);
                }
        if ( getCount == 8){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText3 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText2, 
                    "3", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(3) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText4 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText3, 
                    "4", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(4) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText5 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText4, 
                    "5", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(5) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText6 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText5, 
                    "6", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(6) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText7 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText6, 
                    "7", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(7) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText7);
                }
        if ( getCount == 9){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText3 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText2, 
                    "3", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(3) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText4 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText3, 
                    "4", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(4) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText5 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText4, 
                    "5", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(5) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText6 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText5, 
                    "6", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(6) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText7 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText6, 
                    "7", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(7) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText8 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText7, 
                    "8", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(8) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText8);
                }
        if ( getCount == 10){
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            String story = textView.getText().toString();
            CharSequence modifitedText = Replacer.replace(story, 
                "0", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(0) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText1 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText, 
                    "1", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(1) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText2 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText1, 
                    "2", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(2) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText3 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText2, 
                    "3", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(3) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText4 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText3, 
                    "4", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(4) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText5 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText4, 
                    "5", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(5) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText6 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText5, 
                    "6", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(6) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText7 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText6, 
                    "7", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(7) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText8 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText7, 
                    "8", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(8) +"</font>"));
            CharSequence modifitedText9 = Replacer.replace(modifitedText8, 
                    "9", Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFA500\">"+ values.get(9) +"</font>"));
            textView.setText(modifitedText9);
                }
};}; 


private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    //fill listview with data if statement to get quickstart button to work
    private void fillData() {
        if(main.quickStart == "Cate"){
        Cursor st = mydbhelper.getStory();
            startManagingCursor(st);
            String[] from = new String[] {dbadapter.KEY_TITLESTORY};  
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.outputText};
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.out_row, st, from, to);
            ListView list = getListView();
            View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.outputbutton, list, false);
            View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.outheader, list, false);
            list.addHeaderView(header);
            list.addFooterView(footer);
        setListAdapter(adapter);}
        if(main.quickStart == "Quick"){
            Cursor st = mydbhelper.getQuickStory();
            startManagingCursor(st);
            String[] from = new String[] {dbadapter.KEY_TITLESTORY};  
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.outputText};
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.out_row, st, from, to);
            ListView list = getListView();
            View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.outputbutton, list, false);
            View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.outheader, list, false);
            list.addHeaderView(header);
            list.addFooterView(footer);
        setListAdapter(adapter);}
        }

    public void onClickMenu(View footer){
        final MediaPlayer editClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button50);
        editClickSound.start();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mydbhelper.open();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, 10);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mydbhelper.close();
        super.onPause();
    }
    //Menu Items
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.help:
               showHelp();
                return true;
           }
        return false;
    }

        private void showHelp() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                       this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                     pw = new PopupWindow(
                       inflater.inflate(R.layout.help, null, false), 
                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                       true);
                     pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.outputText), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
        }
        public void onClickHelp(View helper){pw.dismiss();

        }
}
```

Log cat

```
02-28 01:20:09.750: D/dalvikvm(224): GC freed 519 objects / 47136 bytes in 104ms
02-28 01:20:10.360: W/MediaPlayer(224): info/warning (1, 44)
02-28 01:20:10.440: V/DB Exists(224): db exists
02-28 01:20:10.730: I/MediaPlayer(224): Info (1,44)
02-28 01:20:13.260: W/MediaPlayer(224): info/warning (1, 44)
02-28 01:20:13.330: I/MediaPlayer(224): Info (1,44)
02-28 01:20:14.600: W/KeyCharacterMap(224): No keyboard for id 0
02-28 01:20:14.610: W/KeyCharacterMap(224): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-28 01:20:18.851: W/MediaPlayer(224): info/warning (1, 44)
02-28 01:20:18.910: I/MediaPlayer(224): Info (1,44)
02-28 01:20:19.220: D/AndroidRuntime(224): Shutting down VM
02-28 01:20:19.220: W/dalvikvm(224): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-28 01:20:19.220: E/AndroidRuntime(224): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at wanted.pro.madlibs.output$1.run(output.java:45)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-28 01:20:19.240: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 01:20:19.260: I/dalvikvm(224): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-28 01:20:19.300: I/dalvikvm(224): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-28 01:20:21.020: I/Process(224): Sending signal. PID: 224 SIG: 9
02-28 01:20:21.980: D/AndroidRuntime(242): Shutting down VM
02-28 01:20:21.980: W/dalvikvm(242): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-28 01:20:21.980: E/AndroidRuntime(242): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wanted.pro.madlibs/wanted.pro.madlibs.inputpage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at wanted.pro.madlibs.inputpage.onCreate(inputpage.java:51)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-28 01:20:22.000: E/AndroidRuntime(242):  ... 11 more
02-28 01:20:22.020: I/dalvikvm(242): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-28 01:20:22.070: I/dalvikvm(242): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-28 01:20:24.530: D/dalvikvm(250): GC freed 563 objects / 48816 bytes in 78ms
02-28 01:20:24.842: W/MediaPlayer(250): info/warning (1, 44)
02-28 01:20:24.940: V/DB Exists(250): db exists
02-28 01:20:25.022: I/MediaPlayer(250): Info (1,44)
```

Well after a lot of trial and error I was able to get it to work.

```
public class output extends ListActivity {
    private PopupWindow pw;
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;
    private int getCount = inputpage.editCount;
    private Map<Integer, String> values = inputpage.inputValues; 
    public Cursor st;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstantState);
        setContentView(R.layout.outview);
        mydbhelper = new dbadapter(this);
        mydbhelper.open();
        fillData();
        TextView head = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storyTitle);
        st.moveToFirst();
        head.setText(st.getString(st.getColumnIndex(dbadapter.KEY_TITLEDESC)));


    }
```

Think the key was to change and then calling it in the right place/ order. TY for all the help.

```
Cursor st = mydbhelper.getQuickStory();
to 
st = mydbhelper.getStory();
```

Comment: atextview.setText(somestring) is correct.  That works just fine, and there's nothing that we can tell you about it.  If you have some unexpected behavior, or an error, try talking about either.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException in inputpage.java, provide that file code for us to help u.

Answer (score 1):

In your `private void fillData()` if you are comparing strings in **if conditions** then,

`if(main.quickStart == "Cate")` and `if(main.quickStart == "Quick")` are  should be,

```
if(main.quickStart.equals("Cate"))
```

and

```
if(main.quickStart.equals("Quick"))
```

Comment: Changed it over to .equals but still crashes. Everything works fine unless I include the head.setText(st.getString(st.getColumnIndex("titledesc")));

Comment: I think the problem is cursor st. Just remove these two lines, TextView head = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storyTitle);
         head.setText(st.getString(st.getColumnIndex("titledesc")));
and put only System.out.println(st.getString(st.getColumnIndex("titledesc"))); if this also cause exception then just System.out.println(st.getCount()); and check size of cursor.. Simple :-)

Comment: I think there is an issue with the cursor since st.moveToFirst(); is causing problems to. Bot those system.out.println caused it to crash.

Comment: It seems you are unable to get cursor data in your mTask. It remains null.

Comment: I've changed my cursors to have st1, and st2. Next I put System.out.println(st.getCount()); in the filldata instead of on create and it doesn't crash but not sure where its suppose to post results.

Answer (score 0):

here in onResume(),you use your Runnable object.In your runnable,you use Cursor c to set the text for your header title.But the cursor will not be initialized in onResume because you don't call fillData() there.So when your runnable object tries to access cursor c,it will throw an exception.

So you need to change your onResume() like:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        mydbhelper.open();
        fillData();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, 10);
    }
```

Try using this.I hope,it will solve your issue!

Comment: I'll try it. The set text was first in filldata and in on create. In runnable was just the last place I tried before posting here. I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: @maebe: Ok.also check for the spelling of column you use to get the column index and make sure,you have that column created in the table you are accessing.There may be mistake.Also see,the value there is not blank for any case.